# Chrome / IE css incompatibility

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

The first menu item on this site does not display correctly in IE but does so i Chrome. I use css text-indent to create an image menu item.

http://test.suntliv.nu/

In chrome you can see an icon of a house. In IE you see the letters "Sta".

EDIT: I fixed it by giving the first menu item a unique class name.

Answer (score 0):

for IE try using `first-child` instead of `first-of-type`

```
.top-menu li:first-child {
text-indent: -1000px;
background-image: url('../image/icon_home.png');
padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for your effort but it did not change anything.